# Recursive array traversing: same code, different results

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have two short programs that traverse arrays recursively.  The first one prints the array backwards, and the second array prints the array forwards.  The second one is supposed to print the array backwards.  Why is it printing forwards?  It's the same code!!!

Program One:

```
public class SomeClass2 {
    public static String someMethod(int[] array2, int x) {
        if (x < array2.length)
            return String.format("%s%d ", someMethod(array2, x + 1), array2[x]);
        else
            return "";
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        String results = someMethod(array, 0);
        System.out.println(results);
    }
}
```

Program Two:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BackwardsArray {
    
    public static String reverse(char[] array, int x) {
        if (x < array.length)
            return String.format("%s " + reverse(array, x + 1), array[x]);
        else
            return "";
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
        String sentence = input.nextLine();
        char[] charArray = sentence.toCharArray();
        String backwardsSentence = reverse(charArray, 0);
        System.out.println(backwardsSentence);
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: The format is not the same

Comment: What do you mean by "the format is not the same"?  The method someMethod in the first program and the method reverse in the second one are identical.  The code in those two methods is identical.

Comment: See my posted answer

Comment: I found a workaround for it.  Thank you.